# Ionic2 - Selecting sources to compile file build/main.css

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I created a new `Ionic2` project with:

```
$ ionic start MyIonic2Project sidemenu --v2
```

I get this structure:

[image]

If I create the file: `style.scss` under: `/src/assets/css/`, then after compilation, its content is copied inside the generated `index.html`.

In the other hand, if I move this file to: `/src/pages/home/`, then its content is copied to the generated file: `build/main.css`.

I want that if I create the file: `style.scss` under: `/src/assets/css/` then its content be copied to the generated file: `build/main.css` (not to `index.html`).

Is there a place where I configure what files (or file patterns given its directories) are copied to `build/main.css`?